# How to send back image/file in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I need to know how to send image back in aiohttp. I coding a server for image resizing. I used aiohttp.web.FileResponse but it required saved file and it's a bit problem (a lot of files need to be saved on harddrive).

Is there any way to do it flexibly (without saving file)? From image bytes maybe or something? I read aiohttp documentation but it didn't do much.

Here what I tried to do:

1. FileResponse

Here I've got to save it to send response back

```
image = tasks.get(key)  # PIL.Image
image.save('im_server/pil_{}.jpg'.format(key))  
resp = web.FileResponse(f'im_server/pil_{key}.jpg')
return resp
```

2. StreamResponse

When I make request with this code, I've got file back (it's uploading on my computer) but it's not an image. If I try to open it as image, it says file damaged and cannot be opened :(

```
image = tasks.get(key)  # PIL.Image
resp = web.StreamResponse(status=200)
resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'Image/JPG'
await resp.prepare(request)
await resp.write(image.tobytes())
return resp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile` to do the saving job. It is designed to store temp files in the memory and will only save the file on disk if the file size exceeds `max_size` parameter. Notice that this parameter is 0 by default so you need to change it to a suitable size to avoid storing everything on disk. The usage is very simple, `SpooledTemporaryFile` will return a file_like object handle that you can write to it just like a regular file. Once you don't need it, just close it and it will be automatically removed from memory or disk. You may refer to the document to see more usages: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `io.BytesIO`.

```
async def img_resize(req: web.Request):
    data = await req.post()
    url = data.get('url')
    width = data.get('width')
    height = data.get('height')

    if not all((url, width, height)):
        return web.HTTPNotFound()

    try:
        width = int(width)
        height = int(height)
    except ValueError:
        return web.HTTPError()

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with await session.get(url) as res:
            if res.status != 200:
                return web.HTTPNotFound()

            img_raw = await res.read()

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(img_raw))
    im = im.resize((width, height), Image.BICUBIC)

    stream = BytesIO()
    im.save(stream, "JPEG")

    return web.Response(body=stream.getvalue(), content_type='image/jpeg')
```